# Read Output in Batch

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I am using this code to try and download a video+subtitles using youtube-dl and then combine them using ffmpeg.

I am trying to set the video/subtitle output to title.extension instead of the regular title id.extesion, but to do that youtube-dl has a command that outputs it like an echo command, so I need to read it.

```
@echo off
echo Write a link and press enter
set /p link=
cls

youtube-dl.exe -u myusername -p mypassword --skip-download --sub-lang enUS --sub-format "ass" --output "%(uploader)s%(title)s.%(ext)s" "%link%"
youtube-dl.exe -u myusername -p mypassword -f worst --ffmpeg-location "%cd%\ffmpeg.exe" --hls-prefer-ffmpeg --console-title --output "%(uploader)s%(title)s.%(ext)s" "%link%"

youtube-dl.exe -u myusername -p mypassword --skip-download --get-title "%link%" > title.txt
for /f "delims=" %%x in (title.txt) do set title=%%x
ffmpeg.exe -i "%cd%\%title%.flv" -vf "ass=%cd%\%title%.ass" "%cd%\%title%.mkv"
pause
```

Comment: Not quite understanding you.  What code do you use to just get the title without downloading the file? Please show the output of that command as well.

Comment: I am using the code at the bottom (--get-title, but I need it to log in and to not download).
When I run it with [this link](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-477-naruto-and-sasuke-716131) I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/FNG0QiN.png)

Comment: I can't test this at work as I can't put that program on my computer. Can you redirect the output to a file? `youtube-dl.exe -u myusername -p myupassword --skip-download --get-title "%link%" >title.txt`. Basically what I am wondering is if the program only outputs to the console instead of stdout.

Comment: [It outputted it to the text file](http://i.imgur.com/pCuXz3D.png)

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problems running the cmd inside a `FOR /F`.  Can you please update your question to show the exact output of the command to get the title.

Comment: If it is writing the title to the file as a single line and it is the first line of the file then you can read the title back into a variabe using the set command with redirection. `set /p title=<title.txt`

Comment: Thank you, I used for /f and it worked. Now I just need to get youtube-dl to play nice with the link variable.

Comment: In the future, please update your question with information that people ask for.  SO policy is not to post links to answers or questions because the links may become dead.  Also, I work at corporate america where they block most file hosting sites.  So in order to see what you are linking to I have to walk out of my office, pull out my phone and look at what you are trying to show me.

Comment: Your title has a colon in it.  That is not a valid character for a file name.

Comment: I'll switch the links for pics if I can, thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, it works, using the --get-filename option but it gets it with the .flv, when I need to use it for the video and the subtitles, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Fixed the .flv part, but what do I do with the colon? Youtube-dl can't read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, thanks to [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman), I wrote it into a text file after running the command using this to send it to the file:

```
youtube-dl.exe -u myusername -p mypassword --skip-download --get-title "%link%" > title.txt
for /f "delims=" %%x in (title.txt) do set title=%%x
```

And this to set it as a variable called title:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (title.txt) do set title=%%x
```